# Import with or without curly brackets in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What is the difference between:

```
import Title from './title.js'
```

and

```
import { Title } from './title.js'
```

?

I think it has some connection with `export default Title;` and `export const Title;` but I don't know.

Comment: when you are using export default Title you dont need { }

Comment: I was guessing about that but is there an explanation to this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: this question is not specific to angularjs but it is related to ES6 and above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as given in **developer.mozilla.org**

> It is possible to have a default export (whether it is an object, a
>   function, a class, etc.). The import statement may then be used to
>   import such defaults.
>
> The simplest version directly imports the default:

`import myDefault from '/modules/my-module.js';`

**References** : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Answer (score 1):

A module may declare multiple exports. For instance `export const Title;` and `export const SubTitle;`. When you `import` such a module you get an `Object` whose keys are the `export`s you declared.

You can then use function parameter object destructuring - a feature available in ES6 - to select only exports you need from the Object.

Note that parameter destructuring is not available if you use `export default` since `import` will not necessarily return an object, unless that is what you exported.