# import chessjs in node application

Tags: node.js, import, chess

Am quite new to nodejs, so this could be a silly question,  but I hope not.

Am trying to import the [chessjs](https://github.com/jhlywa/chess.js/blob/master/README.md) library in a simple node app.

I have this :

```
const Chess = require('chessjs');
var chess = new Chess();
```

But I get :

```
Error: Cannot find module './chess.js'
```

when I run it despite having installed the lib with npm.

thanks

=========== EDIT SOLUTION ====================

`const { Chess } = require('./node_modules/chess.js/chess.js')`

Comment: Hi allafleche, take a look at the sample code in the 'chessjs' link you posted and compare it to your code, your require statement is not correct

Answer (score 0):

```js
const { Chess } = require('./chess.js')
```

This was from their docs

This might help spread light on whats happening.
[Import with or without curly brackets in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46579940/import-with-or-without-curly-brackets-in-es6)

Comment: I of course tried it before  with 


`const { Chess } = require('./chess.js')`


`"Error: Cannot find module './chess.js'"`


But I get the same error.

Comment: what does the file structure look like?